# Two-body problem, but with one of the bodies fixed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, celestial-mechanics

The two-body problem discusses the orbit of two celestial objects (planets) around each other, often with one of them having **heavier mass** than the other, which has **smaller mass**.

If the **heavier mass** is instead treated as a fixed center of force, and the motion of the lighter mass may be solved for directly by one-body methods, how do the maths of the two-body problem change to accommodate the new assumption of one of the masses being stationary/immobile? or how can that be accounted for in the formula?

Can't understand the following tutorial's language, and I think he's overdoing it

[Reduction of two body problem into one body problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb5iuj3cqCg)

Comment: Please can be more specific about what your difficulty is? Saying that you "can't understand the following (11 minute) tutorial's language" is not helpful.

Comment: He is talking in a language other than english so I can't follow. A walk-through of the reduction here but in english would help

Comment: There are numerous other tutorials available eg https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/2body.htm.

Comment: In order to make the heavier body stationary in the formulas you make its mass much larger than that of the smaller body: $M \gg m$. So $m/M \to 0$.